# Assign a Task to a Queue [Spring 20']

Tags: apex, tasks, queue, spring-20

in Spring 20' Release has been enabled the opportunity to assign a new Task to a queue if it has been added to its supported objects.
Instead of doing that from the UI, I'm trying to do this in ApexCode by assigning the queue's Id directly to OwnerId field of the Task currently in creation, but It returns me a field integrity exception of the type "id value of incorrect type".

Anyone have already done this and can help me?

The following is the executed code:

```
Task t = new Task();
t.Subject = 'SUBJECT';
t.OwnerId = #THEGROUPID / Type='Queue'#;
t.ActivityDate = Date.today();
insert t;
```

Thanks

Comment: Include your code in your question always.Thanks

Comment: Ok, I will do immediately. Thanks

Comment: GenKs, why are you passing type as 'Queue'? Do you have that type available in you picklist? I just ran the code and it is working fine, there is no need to specify type as queue unless you are wanting to pass that value in the code.

Task t = new Task();
t.Subject = 'SUBJECT';
t.OwnerId = '00G41000003JmOOEA0';
t.Type = 'Other';
t.ActivityDate = Date.today();
insert t;

Comment: Raj, sorry, but there is a misunderstanding. The OwnerId Is set as the id of the group that has the type as 'Queue'. In this case the code run in 'field integrity exception'.

Comment: Can you ``System.debug()`` Queue's ID and optionally paste it here?

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that you have selected Task as Supported Object for your Queue:

> Setup -> Queues -> {{your_queue}} -> Edit -> Supported Objects -> Task -> Save.

[image]

Then you can execute this code and everything works fine:

```
Group g = [SELECT Id, Name, Type from Group WHERE Type = 'Queue' AND Name = '{{your_queue}}' LIMIT 1];

Task t = new Task();
t.Subject = 'SUBJECT';
t.OwnerId = g.Id;
t.ActivityDate = Date.today();
insert t;
```

Comment: Hi mariaa, I have done all the steps that you mentioned and the exception comes up anyway.

Comment: Can you provide what id do you set in owner field?

Comment: Have you already tried them?

Comment: Yes, sure, this code worked fine for me.

Comment: Sure, here you are the group id: 00G1X000001rhG1UAI

Comment: @GenKs Is your code being run in a code base lesser than API version 48?

Comment: @DrewKennedy yes, I missed the correct api version. Thank you, now It executes normally.